# Anyone knows how to give individual limited cluster access to users without using RBAC in kube 1.5.7?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to be able to give certain users limited access to the cluster. The admin user is in the kube config but i want to give access to individual users like "bob" but only to just a certain namespace etc. Is the possible without using RBAC?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use ABAC authorization mode: https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/abac/

Comment: Ah perfect! So how do i actually add the policy? using kubectl?

Comment: no, you write a policy file in json and then you specify that file in the API server configuration options ( `--authorization-policy-file=SOME_FILENAME.`)

Comment: also what is the easiest way to restart the api server? It looks like editing that broke kubectl.

Comment: really depends how you are running the api server process ? Systemd ?